# How to hide show cell & footer of section UIollectionview when header Supplementaryview is tapped?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Try to hide and show cell and footer of a section in collection view when head supplementary view is tapped like image below. Try to find some code to do things like this but found none.

Can someone have the workaround for this problem? If possible show how to code it .

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section))
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TenorInterestCell", for: indexPath) as? TenorInterestCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let item = viewModel.itemsForRowAt(indexPath: indexPath)
        cell.tenorText.text = "\(item?.tenorAvailable ?? "") Bulan"
        cell.interestText.text = "Bunga : \(item?.interest ?? 0) %"
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
       
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter {
            let item = viewModel.itemsForRowAt(section: indexPath.section)
          

            guard let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "TenorFooterView", for: indexPath) as? TenorFooterView else {
                fatalError()
            }
            view.tag = indexPath.section

            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(tapDetected))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
            view.configure(with: item)
            view.delegate = self
            return view
            
            
        }else{

          
        guard let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "TenorInterestView", for: indexPath) as? TenorInterestView else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let item = viewModel.itemsForRowAt(section: indexPath.section)
        view.titleText.text = item.prdName
        
        return view
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea  how to solve this?

Comment: One idea If you have just one section, you could make your collectionview the height of the header. When you tap on the header, increase the collectionview height to reveal rest. When you are done, decrease the collection view height again.

Comment: in this case I have numbers of section. @ShawnFrank , or is there any way to make something like that outside using uicollectionview?

Comment: Have a look at: https://swiftsenpai.com/development/collectionview-expandable-list-part1/